# SQLite insert primary key only

Tags: sqlite, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table that is only a single column, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

As it's an autoincrement, How do I insert a value?

I've tried

INSERT INTO Rule DEFAULT VALUES;

which runs but doesn't actually insert anything. any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command creates a column named INTEGER with no type:

```
> CREATE TABLE wrong(INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT INTO wrong DEFAULT VALUES;
> INSERT INTO wrong DEFAULT VALUES;
> SELECT * FROM wrong;
INTEGER
----------
```

If you don't forget the column name, DEFAULT VALUES works just fine with an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column:

```
> CREATE TABLE Rule(RuleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT INTO Rule DEFAULT VALUES;
> INSERT INTO Rule DEFAULT VALUES;
> SELECT * FROM Rule;
RuleID
----------
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `null`:

```
sqlite> create table a(a integer primary key autoincrement);
sqlite> insert into a values(null);
sqlite> insert into a values(null);
sqlite> select * from a;
1
2
```